# Pandas subset selection and Pep8

Tags: python, spyder, pep8

I am using Spyder IDE with code style warnings enabled.
Selecting a subset from a Pandas dataframe via `df[df['Col1'].isna() == False]` triggers the following code style warning.

[image]

The code analysis suggests using `if`. However, `if` does not work in this context. How do I select a subset from a Pandas dataframe without triggering a code style warning?

Comment: Even in a non-Pandas context, `if` would not be appropriate here, of course. But in that context you could use regular negation, i.e. `not somevalue` instead of `somevalue == False`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph except if you want to discriminate `False` from other falsy values (`0`, `None`, `''`…) but that's probably a sign that a refactoring is needed ;)

Comment: @mozway Yeah I'd generally see that (*any* use of boolean literals outside of direct initialisation, in fact!) as a code smell.

Answer (score 3):

For inverse mask in pandas is used `~` instead compare `False`:

```
df[~df['Col1'].isna()]
```

Or use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df[df['Col1'].notna()]
```

Your error is for pure python, not for pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df[df['Col1'].notna()]
```

Or you could invert the mask with `~` (vectorized NOT operator):

```
df[~df['Col1'].isna()]
```